# Files downloaded with ftp_get corrupts/ damages or is too large

Tags: php, ftp, download

I'm using php to download files from the server and save to a users pc, but when I try opening them I am unable to, as it says the file is damaged/ corrupted/ too large, varies depending on file type.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['download']))    
{

    // connect and login to FTP server
    $ftp_server = "**************.**********.***";
    $ftp_username = "a******";
    $ftp_userpass = "******";

    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

    //echo "curr: ".ftp_pwd($ftp_conn) . "\n";

    if (ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, "public_html/files")) {
        //echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($ftp_conn) . "\n";
    } else { 
        echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
    }


    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $selected)
        {
            //echo $selected;

            $local_file = "local.zip";
            $server_file = "$selected";

            // download server file
            if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
            {
                //header("Content-type: application/local.zip");
                header("Content-length: " . filesize($local_file));
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= $selected");

                //echo file_get_contents($local_file);

                unlink($local_file);

                exit();
                //echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
            }
        }
    }
    // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}
```

It's semi doing what I want, but wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong as to why it isn't working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you commented out the line that echoes the file contents?

Comment: I read somewhere that echo statements would cause the download to fail so I was trying what was suggested was all

Comment: What you echo is what will be downloaded. The download will only fail if you echo something in addition to the file.

Comment: @Barmar putting echo file_get_contents($local_file); back in still causes the same error when downloading an image file